# Show that the set {3, 6 , 9 , 12 , 15 ... } is countable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm really confused on how to go about proving this . I had to skip class because of my uni transfer orientation ( go UTD! ) and I'm having a hard time understanding this concept.

Comment: Try the map $\;n\to3n\;$ from the naturals to your set.

Comment: What is your definition of *countable*?

Comment: Any subset of a countable set is countable.  Your set is a subset of the naturals.

Comment: Ok so heres what i got. " Set {3, 6, 9, 12 , 15...} is a subset of N since its an injection of N. the set is countable and a subset of a countable set is also countable. thus the set {3 , 6 , 9 , 12 , 15 ... } is countable as well since its a subset of N."  does it look right?

Answer (score 3):

A comment sayst that your set: $$S = \{3, 6, 9, 12, 15, ...\} \subset \mathbb{N}$$ because every number in your set is an element of $\mathbb{N}$. Because all natural numbers are countable, your set $S$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your definition of countable is actually what some call "countably infinite" in which case it is not true that any subset of a countable set is countable.  With this definition $\{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is not countable.  So definitions are important in this question as one commenter points out.

If your definition of countable is "countably infinite" then to show a set $A$ is countable, we must find a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$.  Another commenter gives you the function to use i.e. consider 
$$f : \mathbb{N} \to \{3,6,9,\ldots\}$$
where 
$$f(n) = 3n$$

It is not hard to show this function is a bijection, i.e. injective and surjective.  To do this show:

*injectivity*: $n \neq m \implies f(n) \neq f(m)$

*surjectivity*: $n \in \{3,6,9,\ldots \} \implies $ there is $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(m) = n$

Comment: Hey, what does $f: \mathbb{N} ...$ mean?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it means $f$ is a function with domain $\mathbb{N}$ and codomain $\{3,6,\ldots\}$